# unable to import wordpress database getting error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Getting this error
ErrorSQL query:---- Database: `dev_weightloss`----

```
----------------------------------- Table structure for table 
`wp_commentmeta`--CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_commentmeta` (`meta_id` 
 bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`comment_id` bigint(20) 
 unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',`meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE 
 utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,`meta_value` longtext COLLATE 
 utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),KEY `comment_id` 
 (`comment_id`),KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT 
 CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;MySQL 
 said: Documentation#1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Open the database sql file in your text editor;**

Open the sql file in your text editor;

Search for **utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci** Replace **utf8_general_ci** Replace all the searches

Search for **utf8mb4** Replace with **utf8** Replace all the searches